# Image Regression: Width of Squares

Tags: keras, regression, image-recognition, conv-neural-network

I have a dataset with lots of pictures and each of these pictures shows me a rectangle with a certain width. My task now is to automatically detect the width of these rectangles by image recognition, and I have trained a CNN for an image regression like in the code below.

However, this CNN gives me very bad values, i.e. mses in the range of 4,000,000 and also a very imprecise estimation of the actual widths. During my experiments I even used the training data set as test data set for the time being, but even here the CNN doesn't seem to learn anything useful.

Do you have an idea what I could be doing wrong? Is it possible that I somehow distort the images themselves while reading them in?

I'm rather new to Machine Learning, so I'm happy about every input you give me! :-)

This is the model:

```
def create_model():
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Convolution2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(64, 64, 3), activation='relu'))
  model.add(Flatten())
  model.add(Dense(64, activation="relu"))
  model.add(Dense(1))
  model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="adam")
  return model
```

And this is the training code:

```
classifier = create_model()

// Getting image id and its corresponding square width
data = pd.read_csv('../data/data.csv')
id_width = data[['id', 'width']]

// Training the model
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator() 
training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=id_width,     directory='../data/images', 
                                          x_col="id", y_col="width", has_ext=True, 
                                          class_mode="raw", target_size=(64, 64), 
                                          batch_size=32)


 classifier.fit_generator(
    training_set,
    epochs=50,
    validation_data=training_set)
```